# VMWare all resolutions displayed full screen HOWTO

Tags: windows-xp, resolution, vmware-player

I installed **Windows XP under VMWare**.
I have full HD screen. When I enter the full screen mode, the resolution will be adapted (there is a VMWARE SVGA II card)
If I change the resolution to 800x600, I only see a **small window** in the middle.
Everything around is a **black border**.

How to say that machine to be full screen at any resolution?

Thanks

Comment: vmware workstation? do you have the tools installed? what's the resolution your monitor runs at right now?

Comment: VMWare Player. I already tried VMWare Workstation, but there is still the same problem. E.g. I got a guest WinXP on full hd monitor. When I set 1024x768 as display res, it will be a small rectangle in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View->Autosize->Stretch guest in Fullscreen Mode (checken in Workstation 8)

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like what you are trying to do: when you resize the VMware window (usually enlarge), your guest resolution doesn't change, and it shows up with black borders all around the display?

In that case, when the virtual machine is running, go to **View -> Fit Guest Now** in VMware, or select **View -> Autosize -> Autofit Guest** to do this automatically, whenever you resize the VMware window.

This will make the virtual machine use all the space available. It will work in fullscreen and window mode.

*Edit: I just realized how old this is, and have no idea how I got here. But maybe this answer will help someone else with the same question...*

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you installed VMWare Tools and after that you can change the desktop settings (right click on desktop-->properties-->settings) to the required screen resolution.

Comment: Yes VMWare Tools was the first SW I installed. But you know where is the problem. I can change resolution, but it takes my real 1 pixel as a dot in the resolution. And want more pixels to have as a dot - with LCD interpolation

Answer (score 1):

re-install **VMWare Tools** and after a restart try **Fit To Guest**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it was driving me mad!

I finally solved it by increasing the Video Memory on the virtual machine.

1. Power off the virtual machine
2. Right click on it in the inventory and go to "Edit Settings..."
3. Click on the Video Card
4. on the right hand side select "Auto-detect settings"
5. Restart the virtual machine
6. Go to Full Screen (For Real This Time!)

I guess the default is "Custom Settings" with 1 display selected and 4MB of Video Memory.  This must not be enough to go full screen on an HD monitor.

Hope This Helps!